# NullPointerException while calculating cost in java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, classnotfoundexception

The following method calculates cost. It access other classes when required. Cloud class holds the information for pricing.

However the method is giving me a nullpointer exception at the following line. 
    BoundaryPrice btp = cloud.getBoundaryPriceMap().get(boundaryType);
The value for totalcost never changes.
Any idea to high light the problem here?

```
private float getCostForConnector(Connector connector)
{
    Cloud cloud = new Cloud("http://amazon.com/europeEC2Clouds#dublinEC2Cloud", dynDesInventory);
    List<Port> portList = getListOfPort(connector);
    Resource root = findCommonRoot(connector);

    Port p1 = portList.get(0);
    Port p2 = portList.get(1);
    float totalCost = 0.0f;
    try
    {
    String rootBoundaryType = getRootBoundaryType();

    Float dataProducedFromP1 = getDataCountForPort(p1);
    Float dataProducedFromP2 = getDataCountForPort(p2);

    List<String> portOnePathOut =  getListOfNetworkBoundary(p1, root);
    List<String> portTwoPathOut =  getListOfNetworkBoundary(p2, root);

        for(String boundaryType: portOnePathOut)
        {
            BoundaryPrice btp = cloud.getBoundaryPriceMap().get(boundaryType);
            if (btp != null)
            {
                totalCost += btp.getOutPrice(boundaryType) + dataProducedFromP1;
                totalCost += btp.getInPrice(boundaryType) + dataProducedFromP2;
            }
        }

        for(String boundaryType: portTwoPathOut)
        {
            BoundaryPrice btp = cloud.getBoundaryPriceMap().get(boundaryType);
            if (btp != null)
            {
                totalCost += btp.getOutPrice(boundaryType) + dataProducedFromP2;
                totalCost += btp.getInPrice(boundaryType) + dataProducedFromP1;
            }
        }

        BoundaryPrice btp = cloud.getBoundaryPriceMap().get(rootBoundaryType);
        if (btp != null)
        {
            totalCost += (dataProducedFromP1 + dataProducedFromP2) * btp.getIntraPrice(rootBoundaryType);
        }


    }catch(NullPointerException e) {
        System.err.println("Caught NullPointerException: ");
    }
    return totalCost;

}
```

Comment: `catch(NullPointerException e) { System.err.println("Caught IOException: ");`. This won't help maintainers.

Comment: "Any idea to highlight the problem here?" NullPointerException should be explicit enough.

Comment: Which line throws the NPE?  e.printStackTrace()?

Comment: Remove the `catch` statement (or add code to show the exception message) and post the exception message here (do not forget to state which line in your example corresponds with the exception message line number!)

Comment: e.printStackTrace(); // much more helpful than simply notifying that an exception has occurred

Comment: No need to repeat questions, please. Read all comments before commenting.

Comment: @dystroy print statement was wrong. NPE occurs beginning of try block.    String rootBoundaryType = getRootBoundaryType(); < code doesn't get executed after this line. stackTrace (org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array.)

Comment: @Wug sorry e.printStackTrace(); was not giving me any details for some reason. I am fairly new to Java and not quite familiar with the e.printStackTrace(); statement. But thanks for the advice though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. One of `portOnePathOut`  and `portTwoPathOut`  lists is null
2. `portList` is null
3. `cloud.getBoundaryPriceMap()` is null
4. `btp.getIntraPrice(rootBoundaryType)` is numeric wrapper and it is null
5. `dataProducedFromP1`  or `dataProducedFromP2` are null
6. `btp.getOutPrice(boundaryType)`, `btp.getIntraPrice(rootBoundaryType)` or `btp.getInPrice(boundaryType)` are null
7. some object *inside functions* you invoke is null

The list would be much shorter next time when you post the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Found the NPE at                       BoundaryPrice btp = cloud.getBoundaryPriceMap().get(boundaryType);      this line